# Having problems centering inline-table

Tags: css, html, centering

I have two minor issues that are driving me nuts.

1) If you visit my site, [Stork](http://trystork.com),you can see that the 3 steps showing how it works and the 3 questions at the footer are aligned to the left. I want them to be centered on the page but I must have missed something because **margin: auto;** isnt working.
Can you please help me center them?

Here is the HTML & CSS for the Steps:

```
<div class="panel">
<div class="title">Step 1: Schedule</div>
<div class="steps">

<p>Schedule a pick up and dropoff with our easy form and let us take care of the rest.</p>

</div>
</div>

.panel {
display: inline-table;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 50px;
width:200px;
height: 180px;
line-height: 1.5;
}
```

And for the questions:

```
<div class="cbox">
<div class="ctitle">How Can I Pay?</div>
<div class="cblurb">
<p>Full payments can be made upon delivery using credit cards only.</p>
</div>
</div>  

.cbox {
display: inline-table;
margin: 50px auto;
padding: 50px;
width:200px;
height: 100px;
line-height: 1.5;
color: #424242;
margin-top:60px;
}
```

2) On a minor note, I am trying to connect the words in the navbar with their respected div classes using the format `href="/.contact"`, but i keep getting an error. how do i fix that?

Thank you!

Comment: inline element can only be centered with text-align on parent.

Answer (score 3):

Add `text-align: center;` to the `panel`'s parent div, that should center your "inline" elements.

If you don't want the contents of the panel to be aligned that way (they will inherit the alignment), add `text-align: left` to the panel's styling.

**Update**

Regarding the second part of your question - you cannot link to an element just using its class (not without javascript, and deciding which element from the collection returned is the one you want as classes are not unique).

An `id`, however, is unique and can be linked to with `<a href="#target_id">Link</a>`

Comment: that seems to have worked, thank you! how about my second issue with linking to classes? do i have to make it an id to work?